# Scala how to use defaults without redefining them

Tags: scala

I have a function defined as:

```
def par(min: Int = -1, exact: Int = -1, auto: Boolean = false) = {
  require(min > 0 || exact > 0 || auto, "Invalid argument")
  OpPar(drm, minSplits = min, exactSplits = exact)
}
```

In another function that uses this I pass in Options for the `par` params. I would like to allow `par` to use it's own defaults but don't see how to do that in Scala (without ugly logic) so I have to redefine, in effect, the defaults like this.

```
drmARaw.par(
  min = minPar.getOrElse(-1),// if par changes this may the be wrong default
  exact = exactPar.getOrElse(-1),// if par changes this may the be wrong default
  auto = autoPar.getOrElse(true))
```

If the defaults ever change this will pass the wrong defaults to `min` and `exact`. Using complicated logic I can decide which version of `par` to call based on which `Option` params are `nonEmpty` for `minPar` and `exactPar` but this is pretty ugly and would have to be written differently for every function with default params. This situation occurs with virtually every Scala lib out there. If they change the defaults and I don't notice it, my code will break.

The example above illustrates the problem but I'm looking for a Scala idiom that would cover *every* case where a function has defaults that could change. I want to write code that is independent of default param changes in lib functions.

Comment: You could use a constant for each default value, i.e. `val MinParDefault = -1`. Then, you could use that in `minPar.getOrElse(MinParDefault)`.

Comment: I can't change the `par` function, it's in a lib.

Comment: My mistake - I meant for `minPar`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I understand it, you have three `Option`s that you need to unpack and send as passed parameters, except if any option is `None` then the invoked method should use its own default value for the missing parameter.

It seems to me your only choice is brute force.

```
(minPar, exactPar, autoPar) match {
  case (Some(m),Some(e),Some(a)) => par(min=m, exact=e, auto=a)
  case (Some(m),Some(e),None)    => par(min=m, exact=e        )
  case (Some(m),None,   Some(a)) => par(min=m,          auto=a)
  case (Some(m),None,   None)    => par(min=m                 )
  case (None,   Some(e),Some(a)) => par(       exact=e, auto=a)
  case (None,   Some(e),None)    => par(       exact=e        )
  case (None,   None,   Some(a)) => par(                auto=a)
  case (None,   None,   None)    => par()
}
```

With 2 parameters it's easy.  With 3 it's manageable.  After that .... painful.

Comment: Truth tables - at least they don't lie to you.

Comment: yes, this is what I meant about ugly logic but you've made it as pretty as can be so I'll accept that this is the best way to do it. I hope the Scala gods are listening ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the logic into a separate `case class` which has a `zero` or `empty` state.

```
case class ParInput(min: Int, exact: Int, auto: Boolean)

object ParInput {
  def apply(min: Option[Int], exact: Option[Int], auto: Option[Boolean]) = {

    ParInput(
      min.getOrElse(empty.min),
      exact.getOrElse(empty.exact),
      auto.getOrElse(empty.auto)
    )
  }
  val empty = ParInput(-1, -1, false)
}
```

Here's the rest of this:

```
def par(input: ParInput = ParInput.empty) = {
  require(min > 0 || exact > 0 || auto, "Invalid argument")
  OpPar(drm, minSplits = input.min, exactSplits = input.exact)
}

def par(
  min: Option[Int] = None,
  exact: Option[Int] = None,
  auto: Option[Boolean] = None
): OpPar = {
  val input = ParInput(min, exact, auto)
  // now call the original library method.
  par(drm, input.min, input.exact)
}
```

Now all you need to update is the empty state, and done. You even get a free Monoid.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yes I agree, typed a little too fast there.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem, it just moves it. The problem is that there seems to be no way to express in Scala that if `minPar == None` I want to use `par`s defaults, whatever they might be. In other words the solution I'm looking for does not contain "-1" or "false". I thought there might be a special value that says, "use the called function's default" or a functional way to hide that logic for any case of this since this seems to come up often when using Scala libs.

Comment: @pferrel Updated, hope I'm not missing anything but this should solve your problem.

Comment: I really appreciate the thought but I can't change `par` nor do I want too. I was looking for a Scala pattern for dealing with a lib function that has default params in a way that can work when the defaults change in general for every case of it (which is quite common).

Comment: @pferrel then you are stuck. You have a function with embedded constants that you cannot or will not refactor. There is no way to query that function for its embedded values.

Comment: Actually @jwvh shows one way to do this, by checking to see what actual values are passed in allowing defaults in `par` to fill in the rest. IMO this is something Scala itself should address.